# Authentication Failure with pgpool using md5

Tags: postgresql, authentication, md5, postgresql-14, pgpool

I am using pgpool 4.3.6 with postgreSQL 14.

The authentication method is set to md5. When attempting to authenticate, I encounter the following error:

```
FATAL:  authentication failed for user ""
DETAIL:  username and/or password does not match
```

I've verified that both pg_hba.conf and pool_hba.conf are configured to use md5 for authentication.

Additionally, the password_encryption setting in postgresql.conf is set to md5, as shown below:

```
show password_encryption;
 password_encryption
---------------------
 md5
(1 row)
```

I also set a password in the pcp.conf file that matches the one in the pool_passwd.

Does anyone have any insights on what might be causing this authentication issue?

Comment: Is "pg_hba.conf" enabled? If not enabled, authentication is managed by Postgres. But if you have opened it, you need to configure this file.

Comment: @samilekesiz Thank you for your comment, but pg_hba.conf is enabled and the authentication method used by pgpool is md5.

Comment: I meant pool_hba.conf. I typed wrong.